# How can i stop activity view indicator after table view data loading

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have UIActivityIndicatorView that i want to start animate in viewdidload before i grab data from API and load into the table view . I then want to stop animating after loading . The problem is , it continues the animation and no data is shown forever . How can i start animating and stop the animation once data is loaded into the table view : This is my code below for the view did load and response method for getting data from api.

```
    public enum indicatorColor {
        static let color : UIColor =  .white
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        activityIndicator.color = indicatorColor.color
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        tableview.isHidden = true
        tableview.separatorColor = .blue
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        response()
    
    }
    
    func response () {
        viewmodel.vmResponse(url: UrlPath.path.shared()) { [weak self](_) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableview.reloadData()
//                self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
//                print(self?.viewmodel.articles)
            }
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, @DMA the activityIndicator.stopAnimating() did not work?

Comment: yes it did not work .

Comment: Any interaction with the activityIndicator did not work or just the stopAnimating()? you can try set activityIndicator.isHidden = true...

Comment: Welcome! Please, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) _it continues the animation and no data is shown forever_ indicates that the block passed to the `viewmodel.vmResponse` is not being called. There's not enough information to answer/help with the problem. Provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you are setting your tableview to hidden. Also, we would need to see that the tableview delegate/datasource implementations have been setup correctly. The most likely culprit is the completion block not being called as zrzka mentioned.

Comment: Can it call completion closure ? I guess completion closure is not called after server response. Have you tried to debug your code starting from DispatchQueue.main.async ?